# How do Islamic theologians study the Bible in countries where studying Hebrew is illegal?

Tags: theology, bible, language

If I am not mistaken, in many Islamic countries studying Hebrew is illegal. Yet, the Koran assumes that the reader is familiar with the Bible. But most of the books of the Bible are originally written in Hebrew. So, how do Islamic theologians in those countries study those books of the Bible?

Comment: The hebrew language is forbidden in many countries ?( for example ?) How do you define an islamic country ?